# Keyboard shortcut on OS X in IntelliJ IDEA 14 to choose button/action in a dialogue box using underlined letter

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, intellij-14

On Windows/Unix in IntelliJ IDEA it is possible to choose a button on an open dialogue box using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>ALT</kbd> + [UNDERLINED_LETTER] where different buttons may have different letters underlined (e.g 2 buttons such as [C]lose and [N]ext can be selected using the keyboard using <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> respectively).

I am trying to find the equivalent of this on OS X. I have checked the official pdf (https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard_Mac.pdf) as well as the keymap settings in IntelliJ itself but it is complicated by the fact that it is not a specific shortcut but varies from dialog to dialog.

Comment: According to this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-133911 it should be CTRL+ALT+letter instead of ALT+letter on Mac. Also check the Appearance settings first to ensure that the mnemonics are not disabled.

Comment: CTRL+ALT+letter stopped working for me when I switched to Apple 1.6 JDK (the only supported osx jdk for intellij see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206827547-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under)